# image URL isn't working anymore

Tags: html, image

I cannot seem to get the following code to work.  I am trying to make it so when you click on my image (`img.banner` in the following code) it navigates to a link.

```
<a href="TargetURL"> </a>
<img class="banner" src="ImageURL" width="8.5%" height="8.5%">
```

Comment: Is your problem that you can not see the image anymore, or that the link on the image does not work anymore?

Answer (score 1):

> "how can I fix this so that when the image is clicked it follows the link?"

Surrounding the image in the anchor tag with the `href` attribute set should turn the actual image into a link.

```
<a href="TargetURL">
  <img class="banner" src="ImageURL" width="8.5%" height="8.5%">
</a>
```

Here is an example

```html
<a href="https://stackexchange.com">
  <img src="https://lh6.ggpht.com/eOJyq2oN2c2EyfzKEZnFOe8cmhKkenRJJ8y637-fZRQKccLqTA4RyFbMqNf0MXeflQ=w300" />
</a>
```

Comment: That worked but now there's a small blue line by the image? any way to avoid this?

Comment: Yes. Add `style="text-decoration: none"` to the anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

If you want clicking on the image to result in following the link, the image must be placed inside the anchor (`<a>` tag)...

```
<a href="TargetURL">
  <img class="banner" src="ImageURL" width="8.5%" height="8.5%">
</a>
```

Comment: That worked but now there's a small blue line by the image? any way to avoid this?

Comment: @HTMLHelp: add following CSS: a {border: 0;}